# Very slow MySQL query (Left-JOIN, GROUP BY, etc. ?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have troubles with the subsequent query, which I submit to a MySQL server. It takes 25s... for (COUNT(*) < 20k)-tables - only featured have 600k rows. However, indexes are created where it should (that is to say : for concerned columns in ON clauses). I tried to remove GROUP BY, which improved the case a bit. But the queries still give a slow response a general rule. I made that post because I could not find a solution into the variety of cases found into stackoverflow. Any suggestion?

```
SELECT
    doctor.id as doctor_id,
    doctor.uuid as doctor_uuid,
    doctor.firstname as doctor_firstname,
    doctor.lastname as doctor_lastname,
    doctor.cloudRdvMask as doctor_cloudRdvMask,

    GROUP_CONCAT(recommendation.id SEPARATOR ' ') as recommendation_ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(recommendation.uuid SEPARATOR ' ') as recommendation_uuids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(recommendation.disponibility SEPARATOR ' ') as recommendation_disponibilities,
    GROUP_CONCAT(recommendation.user_id SEPARATOR ' ') as recommendation_user_ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(recommendation.user_uuid SEPARATOR ' ') as recommendation_user_uuids,

    location.id as location_id,
    location.uuid as location_uuid,
    location.lat as location_lat,
    location.lng as location_lng,

    profession.id as profession_id,
    profession.uuid as profession_uuid,
    profession.name as profession_name
FROM featured as doctor
LEFT JOIN location as location
    ON doctor.location_id = location.id
LEFT JOIN profession as profession
    ON doctor.profession_id = profession.id
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            featured.id as id, 
            featured.uuid as uuid, 
            featured.doctor_id as doctor_id, 
            featured.disponibility as disponibility,

            user.id as user_id, 
            user.uuid as user_uuid
        FROM featured as featured
            LEFT JOIN user as user
                ON featured.user_id = user.id
            WHERE discr = 'recommendation'
        ) as recommendation
        ON recommendation.doctor_id = doctor.id
WHERE
    doctor.discr = 'doctor'
    AND
    doctor.state = 'Publié'
GROUP BY doctor.uuid
```

Here comes the EXPLAIN result:

```
id | select_type | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys              | key                  | key_len | ref                           | rows   | filtered | Extra       |

1 | SIMPLE      | doctor     | NULL       | ref    | discr,state                | discr                | 767     | const                         | 194653 |    50.00 | Using where |
1 | SIMPLE      | location   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                    | PRIMARY              | 4       | doctoome.doctor.location_id   |      1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
1 | SIMPLE      | profession | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                    | PRIMARY              | 4       | doctoome.doctor.profession_id |      1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
1 | SIMPLE      | featured   | NULL       | ref    | IDX_3C1359D487F4FB17,discr | IDX_3C1359D487F4FB17 | 5       | doctoome.doctor.id            |    196 |   100.00 | Using where |
1 | SIMPLE      | user       | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                    | PRIMARY              | 4       | doctoome.featured.user_id     |      1 |   100.00 | Using index |
```

**EDIT** This link helped me, it goes now with 8s. https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/12/mysql-5-7-performance-tuning-immediately-after-installation/. But I still find it slow, I just let it in case anybody would know what could also be improved. Thanks

Comment: `indexes are created where it should `. Where exactly? What is your hardware configuration? Where is EXPLAIN query result?

Comment: Following fields are indexed:

doctor.location_id, location.id
doctor.profession_id, profession.id
featured.user_id, user.id
recommendation.doctor_id, doctor.id
doctor.discr
doctor.uuid

What infos could be useful in the hardware part?

Thank you!

Comment: Compound indexes also very important in some cases. Did you used them? p.s. Also, dump of your database would be nice, so we can test query changes and other stuff with the real db.

Answer (score 0):

I think removing the subquery might help, along with some more indexes:

```
SELECT . . . -- you need to fix the `GROUP_CONCAT()` column references
FROM featured doctor LEFT JOIN
     location location
     ON doctor.location_id = location.id LEFT JOIN
     profession profession
     ON doctor.profession_id = profession.id LEFT JOIN 
     featured featured
     ON featured.doctor_id = doctor.doctor_id LEFT JOIN
     user user
     ON featured.user_id = user.id
WHERE doctor.discr = 'doctor' AND
      doctor.state = 'Publié' AND
      featured.discr = 'recommendation'
GROUP BY doctor.uuid;
```

Then you want an index on `featured(discr, state, doctor_id, location_id, profession_id)` and `featured(doctor_id, discr, user_id)`.

Comment: Just as a test, I completely removed GROUP BY & GROUP_CONCAT stuff, and removed the subquery too. My query, after having verified that all indexes were created, took 7s. I'll edit my post giving the EXPLAIN result

Comment: I don't understand why it still does not work.. I'll do a test on my local machine with the same DB size

Comment: `featured.discr = 'recommendation'` should be in the ON clause.